# Module Not Found Error For Custom Pypi Package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

I am trying to upload my package to pypi and use it. Using Twine i upload it to pypi but when i try to use this package I get Module not found error.

My Error :
[image: Error]

My Folder structure for the package is : 
[image: folder structure]

The error points to the `modelpg/__init__.py` , here's my `modelpg/__init__.py` file.

[image: modelpg/__init__.py]

Is it due to my package name is same as `.py` file.

EDIT 1 :
My `Transformer/__init__.py` file 
[image: Transformer/init_.py]

Comment: Have you tried with " from Trasformer.transformer import * " ?

Comment: Yes but it still shows the same error. The error has something to do with Transformer.transformer . Did i do something wrong in the Transformer package __init__. Py . Wait i will upload that screenshot and pls have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the imports in `modelpg/__init__.py` would need to either be relative:

```
from .Transformer.transformer import Transformer
```

or absolute, with the `modelpg` package name:

```
from modelpg.Transformer.transformer import Transformer
```

This has nothing to do with PyPI, by the way – the same applies even if the package wasn't installed from there.

Comment: Thank you this did work for me. Sorry i made such a simple mistake. Thanks for the input .